# Toon shader with transparency end emission

Tags: shaders, transparency, shadows, emission, toon-shading

I’m creating a new material to use in my works, in this case, it would be a cartoon-style cel shader, I added image support, lineart, among other resources, but some are missing, because I’m having a lot of difficulty adding.

[image]

[image]

I would like to add light effects with emission and transparency, similar to the image below, but in cartoon stile:

[image]

(large image here: https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/standard17/uploads/threejs/original/3X/b/c/bc7626801848b985bf31762cd4e630b72185d9f5.jpeg)

I tried to leave it in the standard way I find in the internet tutorials, but I couldn't use any with my shader.  I've already messed with everything, unfortunately I don't have more knowledge for that.  I really appreciate any tips or help.

Attached is the blender file for those who want to take a look:
https://we.tl/t-fkCX4MhqlT

**Edit:** *Hi! I'm evolving now, I managed to add the emission, and activate the "Bloom" option that I didn't know, but I'm not able to add the transparency, even following Christopher Bennett's tips*

Would this be the case of some other configuration that I don't know about?  thank you for your attention :)

**Here are the current images:**

[image]

(**the black part is where the transparency is supposed to be**)

[image]

Comment: If you're still having problems with transparency, don't forget to change the materials _blend mode_ to something other than "opaque". Alpha-Blend works well for most situations, however  you may want to enable/disable "backface culling" and/or "show backface" to your liking.

Comment: I achieved!  Thanks a lot for the help!!  :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple toon shader - I multiplied the toon shadows over a red color, but you can use any texture you like.

[image: Toon1]

Here is the same shader with the first "ring" replaced with a blue emission and the third ring transparent. I think you should be able to see what I did using the ColorRamps to mask off certain sections to be used as a mix factor for both the Emission and Transparent shaders. Notice that you can mix an unshaded input (MixRGB output) with a Shader input in a Mix Shader - this keeps the toon look from the Shader To RGB setup, while still allowing the blending with other Shader types.

[image: ToonEmit]

Comment: Hi!  Thank you very much for the tip.  :D